# Save model without training in Tensorflow 2.0 with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I use Tensorflow 2.0 and the Keras sequential API to build a model. I would like to save an untrained model for baseline comparison. How do I do that? I tried to set `epochs=0` and `period=0` which did not work.

Here is my code:

```
network = NeuralNetwork() # sequential neural network
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='./models/', save_weights_only=False, period=0)
network.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=0, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

How can I save an untrained model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to call model.save after instanciation of your model :

```
network = NeuralNetwork() # sequential neural network
network.save("/your/path/.h5")
```

ModelCheckpoint can only be called as a callback, so during the training.